# Showing userfom stops processing

Tags: excel, vba

My loading process works fine. I am trying to get it hooked up to a progress bar.

Below is a small sample of code that includes the progress bar.

```
n = the corrent row that is being processed
TotalRecords = total number of rows that needs to be processed

UserForm1.Show

    .Fields(FieldNames(k)) = TableLoc.Offset(n, k - 1).Value

    With UserForm1
        pctCompl = (n / TotalRecords)
        UserForm1.Text.Caption = pctCompl & "% Completed"
        UserForm1.Bar.Width = pctCompl
    End With

    .Update
```

I got the basic idea from [(Displaying A Progress Indicator)](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/displaying_a_progress_indicator/).

The form opens and goes to .04% and then everything just stops.

Answer (score 0):

Showing the form like this blocks the program's flow until you close it.
Open it like this: `UserForm1.Show vbModeless`
At the end, and in case of error, make sure to `Unload UserForm1`